# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.homework2.presentation.MainViewModel.<init>

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-hilt

I am creating android app with Compose using Hilt.
I get info from eternal API, then use Repository->UseCase->ViewModel to get it.

But when i try to initialize my ViewModel in Main Activity I have a lot of problems. In the root of logs is locationg this error: "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:com.example.homework2.presentation.MainViewModel. [] at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332) at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2170) at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:202)... 130 more"

here is my Viewmodel code:

```
data class MainViewState(
    val filmListModel: List<DetailModel> = listOf(),
)

sealed interface MainEvent {
    data class onFilmItemClick(val detailModel: DetailModel) : MainEvent
}

@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getFilmListUseCase: GetFilmListUseCase,
    private val getFilmUseCase: GetFilmUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow<MainViewState>(MainViewState())
    val state: StateFlow<MainViewState>
        get() = _state.asStateFlow()

    private val _film = MutableStateFlow<DetailModel?>(null)
    val film: StateFlow<DetailModel?>
        get() = _film.asStateFlow()

    private val _filmList = MutableStateFlow<Flow<List<DetailModel>>?>(null)
    val filmList: StateFlow<Flow<List<DetailModel>>?>
        get() = _filmList.asStateFlow()

    fun event(mainEvent: MainEvent) {
        when (mainEvent) {
            is MainEvent.onFilmItemClick -> {}
        }
    }

    private val _error = MutableStateFlow<Throwable?>(null)
    val error: StateFlow<Throwable?>
        get() = _error.asStateFlow()


    fun getFilm(id: String){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                getFilmUseCase(id).also { film ->
                    _film.emit(film)
                }
            } catch (error: Throwable) {
                _error.emit(error)
            }
        }
    }

    fun getFilmList(): Flow<List<DetailModel>>{
        lateinit var list:Flow<List<DetailModel>>
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                list = getFilmListUseCase().also { filmList ->
                    _filmList.emit(filmList)
                }
            } catch (error: Throwable) {
                _error.emit(error)
            }
        }
        return list
    }
}
```

this is how i call view model in Activity:

```
@Composable
fun MyScreenContent() {

    val viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
}
```

Maybe (I am sure in it))) I did smth wrong. Help me